# Handlebars, whitespace control

Tags: handlebars.js, whitespace

i want fine control of whitespace but still have readable templates.

Just wanted to see if other's solution to by simple use case.

```
{{name}}
{{#if age}}
  , {{age}}
{{/if}}

# outputs {{name}} , {{age}}
# desire: {{name}}, {{age}}
```

https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/479 - submitted a ticket which was closed.

Comment: Super valid question for anyone using the `:empty` css selector as whitespace invalidates it.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Following the history from [the pull request to add this feature](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/336) it looks like this is the correct syntax:

```
<h4>
{{~#object~}}

Surrounding whitespace would be removed.

{{/object}}
</h4>
```

Result:

```
<h4>Surrounding whitespace would be removed.</h4>
```

**There is also this syntax which trims only leading whitespace:**

```
<h4>
{{~#object}}

Only leading whitespace would be removed.

{{/object}}
</h4>
```

Result:

```
<h4>Only leading whitespace would be removed.
</h4>
```

Comment: As a note, if you want all whitespace removed on looping constructs (like #each), you may need to add tildes on the closing tag as well:

`{{~#each collection~}}{{~/each~}}`

Answer (score 8):

Just a comment to [Brian answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23636497/321731), If you want to trim whitespace AND do not want handlebars to escape your expression at the same time, the correct syntax to be used is:

```
{{~{EXPRESSION}~}}
```

(trimming whitespace before and after the expression while not escaping it)

Answer (score 5):

The Handlebar's Whitespace Control Documentation can be found here: 
https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#whitespace-control

> Template whitespace may be omitted from either side of any mustache statement by adding a ~ character by the braces. When applied all whitespace on that side will be removed up to the first handlebars expression or non-whitespace character on that side.

These two, comma-list examples would have the same output:

**Case 1:**

```
  {{#each listItems as |item index|}}
    {{#if (eq index 0)}}
      {{~item.name~}}
    {{else~}}
      , {{item.name~}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
```

**Case 2:**

```
  {{#each listItems as |item index|}}
    {{#if (eq index 0)~}}
      {{item.name}}
    {{~else~}}
      , {{item.name}}
    {{~/if}}
  {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the cleanest implementation of this would be to add `{{"\n"~}}` where you want a hard-stop on new lines.

The `"\n"` can technically be anything except for empty, ie `""`. I used `"\n"` to make it clear what I am doing in the editor.

**Example**

```
Three empty lines after this



{{"\n"~}}







Three empty lines before this


Two empty lines before this. No empty lines after this.


{{~"\n"~}}


No empty lines before this.
```

**Result**

```
Three empty lines after this



Three empty lines before this


Two empty lines before this. No empty lines after this.No empty lines before this.
```

Basically, as others have said, any helper can be prefixed or suffixed with `~`. Here, I've decided to pass a value that won't render as the helper (`"\n"`) which allows us to pass `~` freely to control before and after whitespace.

## Edit

Alternatively:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper(
  'singleLineOnly',
  function (options) { // "this" cannot be provided to inline function!
    return options.fn(this).replace(/[\r\n]+/gm, '')
  }
)
Handlebars.registerHelper(
  'singleSpaceOnly',
  function (options) { // "this" cannot be provided to inline function!
    return options.fn(this).replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')
  }
)
```

Which will allow you to take something like this:

```
{{#each this}}
  {{#singleLineOnly}}
  {{#singleSpaceOnly}}

  {{calculatedAmount}}

  {{!an example comment}}
  {{#if unitOfMeasure.translate}}
    {{{unitOfMeasure.translate.value}}}
  {{/if}}

  {{!some random comment}}
  {{#unless unitOfMeasure.translate}}
    {{{unitOfMeasure.value}}}
  {{/unless}}

  {{!Some random comment}}
  {{#ifNotEquals (lowerCase product.value) "other"}}
    {{!If translated, use translated UOM}}
    {{#if product.translate}}
      {{{product.translate.value}}}
    {{/if}}
    {{!If not translated, use default UOM}}
    {{#unless product.translate}}
      {{{product.value}}}
    {{/unless}}
  {{/ifNotEquals}}

  {{!just some more logic for example}}

  {{#ifNotEquals (lowerCase ingredient.value) "other"}}
    {{!If translated, use translated UOM}}
    {{#if ingredient.translate}}
      {{{ingredient.translate.value}}}
    {{/if}}
    {{!If not translated, use default UOM}}
    {{#unless ingredient.translate}}
      {{{ingredient.value}}}
    {{/unless}}
  {{/ifNotEquals}}
  <br/>

  {{/singleSpaceOnly}}
  {{/singleLineOnly}}
{{/each}}
```

And end up with this:

```
1/2 oz. first ingredient <br/>
1 pump(s) another ingredient <br/>
3/4 oz. this ingredient <br/>
2 shot(s) that ingredient <br/>
last instruction <br/>
```

`{{#singleLineOnly}}` and `{{#singleSpaceOnly}}` can be used as a wrapper for any text. You'll most likely want to use these  with `~` for additional before/after whitespace control. For example: `{{~#singleLineOnly~}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Handlebars Helper to `trim()` whitespace

```
{{#-}}

Surrounding whitespace would be removed.

{{/-}}
```

more background info: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/336

Comment: You should have read the link you sent properly. On Oct 15 2013 the syntax was locked as tilde and it was planned as a part of the language (it is now). So e.g. `{{#if something~}}    a  {{~/if}}` removes whitespaces between the opening tag and a, and then between a and closing tag. The background info is good. The answer itself is rather poor and should be deleted or edited. Downvoting.

Comment: A lot has changed, that's for sure. But this was released in Nov '13