# How to remove newlines generated by Handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js

Suppose I have a template like the following:

```
start
{{#if data}}
data
{{/if}}
end
```

Regardless of what I pass to the template, it will always have two extra newlines:

```
start

data

end
```

Is there a way to have Handlebars not generate the newlines that the tags were occupying (without moving the tags themselves)? eg.

```
start
data
end
```

The reason why I want this is because there are cases (like in XML), where newlines are not desirable.

For example the following:

```
<parent>
    {{#each}}
        <child>{{.}}</child>
    {{/each}}
</parent>
```

Will generate

```
<parent>

    <child>foo</child>

    <child>bar</child>

</parent>
```

Collapsing the {{#each}}, {{/each}} to a single line will cause Handlebars to generate lists on a single line as well. For example, this:

```
 <parent>
     {{#each}}<child>{{.}}</child>{{/each}}
 </parent>
```

Will generate

```
 <parent>
     <child>foo</child><child>bar</child>    
 </parent>
```

So in order to generate XML without extraneous newlines, my templates end up looking something like this:

```
 <parent>{{#each}}
     <child>{{.}}{{/each}}
 </parent>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution that does not involve saving the document under a different encoding?

Comment: @MarkLopez Yes, you can try this: http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#whitespace-control

Comment: Ironically I found another solution to my problem. My IDE was saving the files with the second new line character common on Windows systems. Handle bars was not removing the character correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you prevent newline added to Handlebars partial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317474/how-do-you-prevent-newline-added-to-handlebars-partial)

Answer (score 20):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317474/how-do-you-prevent-newline-added-to-handlebars-partial?stw=2). Try adding swung dash to the brackets, e.g., {{> partial ~}} instead of {{> partial}}, this will remove the newline. In your case, it would be:

```
start
{{#if data ~}}
data
{{/if ~}}
end
```

Which would compile to:

```
start 
data 
end
```

Comment: I've been using Handlebars for years and didn't know this. I was going to write up some cleanup script. Now I don't need to. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

For those landing here trying to remove all subsequent trailing lines, I think the cleanest implementation of this would be to add `{{"\n"~}}` to the end of any concerning lines.

The `"\n"` can technically be anything except for empty, ie `""`. I used `"\n"` to make it clear what I am doing in the editor.

**Example**

```
start{{"\n"~}}
data
end
```

**Result**

```
startdata
end
```

---

**Example**

```
start{{"\n"~}}



data
end
```

**Result**

```
startdata
end
```

---

**Example**

```
start{{"\n"~}}


data{{"\n"~}}


end
```

**Result**

```
startdataend
```

## Edit

Alternatively:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper(
  'singleLineOnly',
  function (options) { // "this" cannot be provided to inline function!
    return options.fn(this).replace(/[\r\n]+/gm, '')
  }
)
Handlebars.registerHelper(
  'singleSpaceOnly',
  function (options) { // "this" cannot be provided to inline function!
    return options.fn(this).replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')
  }
)
```

Which will allow you to take something like this:

```
{{#each this}}
  {{#singleLineOnly}}
  {{#singleSpaceOnly}}

  {{calculatedAmount}}

  {{!an example comment}}
  {{#if unitOfMeasure.translate}}
    {{{unitOfMeasure.translate.value}}}
  {{/if}}

  {{!some random comment}}
  {{#unless unitOfMeasure.translate}}
    {{{unitOfMeasure.value}}}
  {{/unless}}

  {{!Some random comment}}
  {{#ifNotEquals (lowerCase product.value) "other"}}
    {{!If translated, use translated UOM}}
    {{#if product.translate}}
      {{{product.translate.value}}}
    {{/if}}
    {{!If not translated, use default UOM}}
    {{#unless product.translate}}
      {{{product.value}}}
    {{/unless}}
  {{/ifNotEquals}}

  {{!just some more logic for example}}

  {{#ifNotEquals (lowerCase ingredient.value) "other"}}
    {{!If translated, use translated UOM}}
    {{#if ingredient.translate}}
      {{{ingredient.translate.value}}}
    {{/if}}
    {{!If not translated, use default UOM}}
    {{#unless ingredient.translate}}
      {{{ingredient.value}}}
    {{/unless}}
  {{/ifNotEquals}}
  <br/>

  {{/singleSpaceOnly}}
  {{/singleLineOnly}}
{{/each}}
```

And end up with this:

```
1/2 oz. first ingredient <br/>
1 pump(s) another ingredient <br/>
3/4 oz. this ingredient <br/>
2 shot(s) that ingredient <br/>
last instruction <br/>
```

`{{#singleLineOnly}}` and `{{#singleSpaceOnly}}` can be used as a wrapper for any text. You'll most likely want to use these  with `~` for additional before/after whitespace control. For example: `{{~#singleLineOnly~}}`

Answer (score 0):

The answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24342015/54426) did not work for me using express-handlebars 3.0.0. What did work was a slight variation:

```
{{~#each children~}}
  {{this}}
{{~/each~}}
```

I found this solution in this answer to a related question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23636497/54426