# How do you prevent newline added to Handlebars partial?

Tags: javascript, html, template-engine, handlebars.js

Scenario: one-line Handlebars partial used in an inline element:

Handlebars template:

```
<a href="#section">{{> partial}}Label</a>
```

Partial:

```
<svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 65 65"><use xlink:href="#icon"></use></svg>
```

Compilation result:

```
<a href="#section"><svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 65 65"><use xlink:href="#icon"></use></svg>
Label</a>
```

As you see, partial comes across with the newline. There's no newline in the file.

Comment: Are you precompiling ur templates? Maybe BOM character is getting added.

Comment: Checked against it, used `:set nobomb` and resaved (in Vim), still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the Vim's EOL management.

To prevent newline appearing after the Handlebars compilation, change Vim configuration (`.vimrc`) to include:

```
au BufWritePre * :set binary | set noeol
au BufWritePost * :set nobinary | set eol
```

Answer (score 5):

It's on the handlebarsjs.com,
but not documented well enough (for me);

after a half an hour of struggling wandering where exactly am I supposed to set this "~"

```
{{#each arrayOfItems ~}}
<div>
{{~> item ~}}
</div>
{{~each}}
```

aaand, works like a charm for me:)

(handlebars-express3 on Node.js)

Comment: Thanks for the post, although, it regulates the whitespace, not newline. The newline behaviour wasn't Handlebars-related after all, it was about eol injected by Vim as you see from the accepted answer of my own :)